# Divide entire dataframe by 2 using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to divide my entire dataframe by 2 in Python

**Data**

```
id      date    aa  bb  cc  dd
staff   Q1 23   6   2   6   0
staff2  Q2 23   6   2   6   0
```

**Desired**

```
id      date    aa  bb  cc  dd
staff   Q1 23   3   1   3   0
staff2  Q2 23   3   1   3   0
```

**Doing**

```
df.div(2)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Receiving TypeError - update

*Wish to divide numerical columns by 2*

Comment: is `df.div(2)` not working?  What is the issue

Comment: `df.set_index(['id', 'date']).div(2)` or `df[df.columns[2:]] = df[df.columns[2:]].div(2)`

Comment: It is giving a type error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float' - perhaps I must convert

Comment: That's because your question is incorrect - you need to only divide the numerical columns, not the entire dataframe.

Comment: The error info should be added to the question

Comment: ok @It_is_Chris this works - I will include the error in the posted question

Comment: @Lynn you can only do the operation on a subset of columns as suggested above.

Comment: @gshpychka makes sense, just updated post - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need select the number

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(np.number)/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

check for float 64 and int 64 data type for a column name then use the column to divide by 2 the results

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int64']).columns:
        df[col] = df[col] / 2
```